# After adding an object to and array original object is overwritten

Tags: vba, excel

I have a method that is adding custom objects to an array in a loop. The problem is, that the last object added to the array seems to overwrite all the other objects in the array. I have stepped through the code to see that the correct objects are added initially but I can't seem to figure out why the last object overwrites all others. I have a feeling that it has something to do with memory pointers and my CallNum object but I haven't been able to figure this one out.

```
Function getCallNumObjects(TotalCol As Integer) As Lib_CallNum
'
'   Find all the call numbers and their coresponding total
'
    Dim CallNumObjs() As Lib_CallNum
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 0
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "$<total:U>"
        If i <> 1 Or i <> 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve CallNumObjs(i) As Lib_CallNum
        End If
        Dim CallNum As New Lib_CallNum
        CallNum.Title = Replace(ActiveCell.Value & ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value, " ", "")
        CallNum.Total = ActiveCell.Offset(0, TotalCol - 1).Value
        Set CallNumObjs(i) = CallNum
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Activate
        Debug.Print CallNumObjs(i).Title
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    Debug.Print CallNumObjs(0).Title
    Debug.Print CallNumObjs(1).Title
    Debug.Print CallNumObjs(2).Title



    Set getCallNumObjects = CallNumObjs
End Function
```

**The output of this function is:**

DS0000701-DS000800

LH-PK

PL001001-PL003300

**The prints after the loop are:**

PL001001-PL003300

PL001001-PL003300

PL001001-PL003300

Comment: One thing to note is that the line: If i <> 1 Or i <> 0 Then will always be true, which is good, otherwise those elements wouldn't get filled.  I think you can just delete it.

Comment: Those would not always evaluate to true, The loop goes through more than 2 times on many occasions. So sometimes i > 1

Comment: What I meant was that i is always not equal to 1 or not equal to 0.  If i equals 1, it's not equal to 0 and vice-versa, so the statement always evaluates to True.  I believe you mean to use an AND statement.  But if you do, then the array won't be dimensioned until i hits 2, and your code will fail on the line: Set CallNumObjs(i) = CallNum, when i = 0 or i = 1.

Comment: Good call, you were right I didn't need the if.

Comment: Sadly, I can't see why you're getting the debug.print results you describe.  I'm going to edit my answer with a more common coding structure though and see if that helps.

Comment: Turns out it was a weird answer I needed to change my initialization of my Lib_CallNum object from:

Dim CallNum As New Lib_CallNum
To:
Dim CallNum As Lib_CallNum
Set CallNum = New Lib_CallNum
But I am unsure why the first initialization would not work. Could anybody answer this for me?

Comment: Perhaps because you kept declaring it as New, but never set it to Nothing.  I started to just fix that in my answer, but don't think you need that intermediate variable at all.  Just fill the array directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CallNumObjs is an array of Lib_CallNum.  The function assigns that array to a single instance of Lib_CallNum, not an array.  Perhaps if your function was defined as:

```
Function getCallNumObjects(TotalCol As Integer) As Lib_CallNum()
```

EDIT: I incorporated the change from the comments and deleted the intermediate CallNum variable.  This might at least clear out unneeded stuff for debugging.  Also, I think the repeated instantiation of that variable might have caused your problem:

```
Function getCallNumObjects(TotalCol As Integer) As Lib_CallNum ()
    Dim CallNumObjs() As Lib_CallNum
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 0
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "$<total:U>"
        ReDim Preserve CallNumObjs(i) As Lib_CallNum
        CallNumObjs(i).Title = Replace(ActiveCell.Value & ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value, " ", "") = CallNum
        CallNumObjs(i).Total = ActiveCell.Offset(0, TotalCol - 1).Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Activate
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Set getCallNumObjects = CallNumObjs
End Function
```

Comment: Wasn't quite the answer to my problem but I did need to change it to return Lib_CallNum()

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue when adding new custom class objects to an array, and while this post did point me to the answer, it was a bit buried. So, I'm clarifying it here. The issue was with how each new object to be added to the array was initialized.

instead of initializing the object like this:

```
Dim CallNum As New Lib_CallNum
```

we need to do this:

```
Dim CallNum As Lib_CallNum
Set CallNum = New Lib_CallNum
```

Seems unnecessarily verbose, but at least it works.